# What is the potential threat if I "Unrestricted' the Execution Policy for Local Machine?

Tags: powershell, oh-my-zsh

I installed oh-my-posh but the profile script for PowerShell was not working correctly. I found out PowerShell execution policy is restricted by default. I have changed the setting following Microsoft's About Execution Policy page.

What is the security threat of unrestricted execution?

Comment: The threat is that PowerShell will now execute any script you ask it to, regardless of whether it was _digitally signed_. It's NOT a security boundary, it's a "let's-prevent-users-from-shooting-themselves-in-the-foot" boundary :)

Comment: In addition to what Mathias said above, if you are working on a Windows domain, there is absolutely no reason to not sign your scripts. The process is quite simple, if you choose to go down this route - Follow [Part 1 & 2](https://sysadminplus.blogspot.com/2016/08/stop-running-unsecure-scripts-how-to.html) at least, ignoring the part about installing a Certificate Authority if you already have one. Once configured it takes little to no effort to add your cert to a script or module.

Comment: You might check [PowerShell Security Best Practices](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-security-best-practices/) with the video recorded and available here: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Blue-Hat-Security-Briefings/BlueHat-Security-Briefings-Fall-2013-Sessions/PowerShell-Best-Practices)

Answer (score 1):

The default is remotesigned now anyway.  But anyone can override it by running "powershell -executionpolicy bypass".  The purpose is to stop *unknowingly* running a PowerShell script, say from an email attachment, like the good old days of getting vbscripts in email.